# how to Attach a generated Barcode to email in Prestashop 1.7.5

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Can anyone please help me,
i would like to attache a generated Barcode image (png) in the order_conf email

i started by generate the barcode image :

```
$barcodeobj = new TCPDFBarcode($order->order_barcode, 'C128');

$barcode = base64_encode($barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG(1, 30, array(255,255,255)));
```

and then :

```
Mail::Send(
(int) $order->id_lang, 'order_conf',
Context::getContext()->getTranslator()->trans( 'Order confirmation', array(), 'Emails.Subject', $orderLanguage->locale ),
$data,
$this->context->customer->email,
$this->context->customer->firstname . ' ' . $this->context->customer->lastname,
null,
null,
$barcode,
null,
_PS_MAIL_DIR_,
false,
(int) $order->id_shop
);
```

also i tried to attache it like this but i didn't work :

```
$extra_pdf = array();

$extra_pdf['content'] = $barcode.'.png';

$extra_pdf['name'] = 'barcode.png';

$extra_pdf['mime'] = 'image/png';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the content of your image :

```
$content = file_get_contents(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/your_img_barcode_folder/'.$barcode.'.png');
```

Source:
http://prestacraft.com/send-custom-template-email-with-attachment-and-variables-in-prestashop/#

or you can also create a simple $link in your email template